# Why Firefox rounds font size in canvas context if font size is less than 15px, but not if is greater than 15px?

Tags: firefox, fonts, html5-canvas

In Firefox, font size is rounded if less than 15px for the following example.

```js
const text = "Life is not a problem to be solved, but a reality to be experienced.";
// this produces the same result
ctx.font = "14.6px Arial"; // it will render as 15px
ctx.fillText(text); 
// as 
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText(text); 

// this produces the different result
ctx.font = "15.6px Arial"; // it will render as 15.6px
ctx.fillText(text); 
// than
ctx.font = "16px Arial"; // it will render as 16px
ctx.fillText(text);
```

The same example in Chrome is working correctly.
I tried it in the newest available Firefox (91.0.2 64-bit) on Windows 10, but I also tried older versions of Firefox (for example version 60 from 2018) to exclude that it is the bug in the newest version. With the older version, it is the same.
Extensive searching on the internet didn't give me any significant results.

**Is there anything I can do to make it working correctly in Firefox also for font size less than 15px?"**

You can try and play with the example on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-hypatia-j9c8p?file=/index.html:0-1056

*Additional info update:*
It seems that for some fonts it is working correctly, and for some not. sans-serif and Arial don't work.

Comment: Why do you set a decimal pixel value for a font size at all? 15.6px won't render as 15.6 pixels.

Comment: @obscure: It is related with custom scaling in my app. If you try my example, you can see that for 15.6px and 16px there is different width so decimal places obviously makes difference. But for 14.6px and 15px is the same text width. In Chrome it is different also for 14.6px and 15px. Do you have some idea why it doesn't work correctly in Firefox if font size isn't greater than 15px?